# VPC - able to connect if 0.0.0.0/0 but not if I specify anything more specific

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

When at home, I have been able to access my personal EC2 instance with SSH on Port 22.

When at work, I cannot. I'm using Putty with SSH and I get

> Network Error: Connection Timed Out.

If I open up security on the port: `0.0.0.0/0` - it works. Putty connects and I can use my EC2 instance. So I'm assuming that means it isn't a firewall issue. Is that a valid assumption?

When I hit, http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ and replace the `0.0.0.0/0` with that address plus /32 (or even /64, /24 or /16) it doesn't work.

This is true for all my ports, not just 22. I would rather not keep any port so open, especially 22, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: If you refresh http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ does it change? Maybe you are behind some sort of proxy that uses more than one IP address?

Comment: No. I first tried this a few weeks ago, and the IP address is the same as then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is 2 entries for SSH access. One from home and one from work. Edit the security group attached to the instance and allow your current IP to access it.
[image]

Do it at work and at home. Now both home and work IPs can access your instance through SSH assuming your IP doesn't change over time. Also, what do you mean by you **cannot SSH**? Can you post the out put of `ssh -v -i ......`?
*

Once you connect with `0.0.0.0/0`, in the terminal try `echo $SSH_CONNECTION` or `echo $SSH_CLIENT`. It will list the IP you connected from. Check if the IP matches the one in the security group. If it doesn't match, update the security group with the correct IP and try again.

From `man ssh`:

```
 SSH_CONNECTION        Identifies the client and server ends of the connection.  The variable contains four space-separated values: client IP address, client port number, server IP address, and
                       server port number.
```

Comment: I have 2 rules, one for work and one for home. Home is specific to my IP at home with a rule of X.X.X.X/32, and it works using Putty ssh on port 22. I take my laptop to work, I used the `checkip` to get an IP address, I added a second SSH rule. Then I try to connect via the same putty connection and get a "Nework error: Connection timed out". I used a rule of X.X.X.0/24. If I change the work rule to '0.0.0.0/0', then I can successfully connect with Putty at work.

Comment: Once you connect with `0.0.0.0/0`, in the terminal try `echo $SSH_CONNECTION` or `echo $SSH_CLIENT`. It will list the IP you connected from. Check if the IP matches the one in the security group. If it doesn't match, update the security group with the correct IP and try again.

Comment: BOOM! That did it. Do you have a link to documentation where I could have answered that for myself?

Comment: @RobertB, `man ssh` lists all variables in the `ENVIRONMENT` section. Was the IP different from the one `checkip` returned?

Comment: Yes it was. Only the first number matched.